# MySQL finding all ids in a hierarchal list

Tags: mysql, sql, recursion, recursive-query

I have an SQL table that looks like this.

```
    id | parent_id
    1  | 2
    2  | 4
    3  | 5
    4  | 6
    7  | 5
    8  | 7
```

What I need is a list of all id's that don't have have parents and all the id's under those. Something like.

```
   parent_id | id
   6 | 4
   6 | 2
   6 | 1
   5 | 7
   5 | 8
   5 | 3
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What version of MySQL? You'll need 8.0 for hierarchical/recursive queries.

Comment: Please add the DDL (create table ...) statement, since the requirements are not clear.

Comment: It seems all ids in your example have parents. How did you come up with the second list?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you want...

Maybe this:

```
SELECT parent_id,id FROM table ORDER BY parent_id DESC, id DESC;
```